# Typescript extend object that implements interface with dynamic properties

Tags: typescript

I have an object that implements an interface:

```
interface ILoadedComponent {
    property1:string;
    property2: numberl;
}
class SomeClass {
    loadedComponent:ILoadedComponent = {
        property1:'x',
        property2: 10
    }
}
```

But I want to expend on the implemented interface with additional properties:

```
class SomeClass {
        loadedComponent:ILoadedComponent = {
        property1: 'x',
        property2: 10,
        property3: 'y',
        property4: 60
    }
}
```

For expending on the implemented interface I get a compiler error:

```
 ... is not assignable to type SomeClass ...
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'property3' does not exist in type 'SomeClass '.
```

How can I expend on an interface with an object literal

Comment: That's because of excess property checking on object literals. You can go with `as ILoadedComponent` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBkD2cAmEcDCmAtgA6YgTjIDeAUMo8qVJqdGAJ4CMAXAM5gooAOYBuBkxZsOnAEy9kIAK7EARtAkBfOggA2cfv2QBlEhAIGjtSYz3Y8hEuUrUAvDaZfmrdlC58yADkAB5BADS23tJ+XArI3AAMkd5SvrIAzIpBnBFRXjGyACyKAGyJUVrIhmhYuPhEZBRUYHRaQA

Answer (score 0):

@Tomas Katz , you have wrongly implemented an interface, you have created the property in `SomeClass` of type `ILoadedComponent` component.

If you want to implement an interface and add new properties you have to use it as below

```
class SomeClass implements ILoadedComponent{
        property1: 'x',
        property2: 10,
        property3: 'y',
        property4: 60
}
```

if you want to use a `loadedComponent` Property in `SomeClass` then you have to create a separate class which implements the interface or you have to `extend` `ILoadedComponent` interface in another interface and use that interface in `SomeClass`

Comment: But I need the object loadedComponent in the SomeClass to implement the interface, not the class intself... maybe i need to use type?

Comment: Then you have to create a separate class which implements the ILoadedComponent and add extra properties, and use that class as a type in `SomeClass`

Comment: but i want to add properties dynamically... unknown dynamic properties